# React-Native Updating state array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-state-management

I have a state holding an array of objects (players) that I retrive from my API and then I'm rendering the users avatar on screen using the map function

```
   {players.map(player => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={player._id}
          style={selectedPlayers.inclues(player) ? styles.userAvatarContainerSelected : styles.userAvatarContainer}
          onPress={() => handlePlayerAvatarClick(player)}
        >
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: player.avatar_url
            }}
            style={styles.userAvatar}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    })}
```

My problem here is that when I tap the button I want to update a state of a state called selectedPlayers so I can update the style accordingly and then retrive the state back to the API.
I'm inicializing the state as `const [playersAvatars, setPlayersAvatars] = useState([]);`

And the handlePlayerAvatarClick function is:

```
function handlePlayerAvatarClick(newPlayer) {

    if (newPlayer in selectedPlayers) {
      const arrayWithRemovedPlayer = selectedPlayers.filter(player => player._id.equals(newPlayer._id));

      setSelectedPlayers(arrayWithRemovedPlayer);
    }

    setSelectedPlayers(...selectedPlayers, newPlayer);
  }
```

I'm getting an error saying that selectedPlayers.includes() is not a function I don't get the problem, if I run `Array.isArray(selectedPlayers)` it returns `true` so, in theory, I could use the array functions like includes().

Any idea on what the issue is?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to do: `setSelectedPlayers([...selectedPlayers, newPlayer]);` But it would be better if you do the callback version: `setSelectedPlayers(selectedPlayers=>[...selectedPlayers, newPlayer]);` Then you can useCallback for handlePlayerAvatarClick and maybe optimise your list with a Player component that is a pure component.

Comment: Yes I realized the first part just moments after posting the issue. About the useCallback hook I never used it and never explored the hook deeply could you elaborate on how it would be beneficial in the app please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not pass the correct value to setSelectedPlayers and should have done `setSelectedPlayers([...selectedPlayers, newPlayer])`.

Here is an optimised version where I use the callback version of state setter `setSomeState(oldvalue=>newValue`:

```js
//using React.memo will make Player a pure
//  component and won't re render if props didn't change
const Player = React.memo(function Player({
  player,
  isSelected,
  handlePlayerAvatarClick,
}) {
  const r = React.useRef(0);
  r.current++;
  return (
    <li
      onClick={handlePlayerAvatarClick(player)}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
    >
      rendered:{r.current} times, name: {player.name}, is
      selected:
      {isSelected.toString()}
    </li>
  );
});
const players = [
  { id: 1, name: '1', completed: false },
  { id: 2, name: '2', completed: false },
];

function App() {
  const [
    selectedPlayers,
    setSelectedPlayers,
  ] = React.useState([]);
  //use callback so the handler never changes
  const handlePlayerAvatarClick = React.useCallback(
    (player) => () =>
      setSelectedPlayers((selectedPlayers) =>
        selectedPlayers.includes(player)
          ? selectedPlayers.filter((p) => p !== player)
          : [...selectedPlayers, player]
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {players.map((player) => (
        <Player //player is pure and won't re render if nothing changed
          key={player.id}
          player={player}
          isSelected={selectedPlayers.includes(player)}
          handlePlayerAvatarClick={handlePlayerAvatarClick}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```